# Why does stating that the cdf $FZn(a) \to N(\mu,\sigma)$ leads to $P\{|Z_n - \mu| > \sigma\} = 1 - F_{Z_n}(\mu + \sigma) + F_{Z_n}((\mu + \sigma)^-)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am am trying to understand [this proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22587/92423) of why we can't deduce the law of large numbers from the Central limit theorem.

The central limit theorem states that **the mean of i.i.d. variables, as N goes to infinity, becomes normally distributed**.

I know I will be wrong but that makes me think that for i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the cumulative distribution function $F_{Z_n}(a)$ of
$$Z_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
converges to the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$, a normal random
variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  Or, the distribution of $Z_n - \mu$ converges to the distribution of $\mathcal N(0,\sigma)$, or the distribution of $(Z_n - \mu)/\sigma$ converges to the distribution of $\mathcal N(0,1)$, the standard normal random variable.

I don't understand why this statement implies that:

$$P\{|Z_n - \mu| > \sigma\} = 1 - F_{Z_n}(\mu + \sigma) + F_{Z_n}((\mu + \sigma)^-) \to 1-\Phi(1)+\Phi(-1) \approx 0.32$$
as $n \to \infty$.

In particular I don't understand:

- why the probability of the sandardized normal distribution of n variables minus its to be greater than its variance is eaqual to 1 - the cumulative distribution of thea mean minus plus the variance plus the cumulative distribution of its opposite. That is to say: $$P\{|Z_n - \mu| > \sigma\} = 1 - F_{Z_n}(\mu + \sigma) + F_{Z_n}((\mu + \sigma)^-)$$
- And I don't undersand this notation $F_{Z_n}((\mu + \sigma)^\bbox[5px,border:3px solid red]{-})$. Does it means it goes to $-(\mu + \sigma)$?

I am a data scientist but I come from literature background. I would be very happy if you could explain it to me very simply, like to a teenager, or even with explicit examples or charts.

Comment: usually $f(x-):=\lim_{y\to x^-}f(y)$, and in this case this is the meaning

Comment: @Masacroso I'm really sorry but it is the first time I encounter this notationwithouth a $^{-number}$. Does it means that it goes to $-x$?

Comment: See, for instance, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit